# Dart code error says Nyxx is not defined although I imported the library

Tags: dart, discord, bots

I am writing a discord bot in dart that changes the name every day. However I am getting an error saying that the function 'Nyxx' is not defined although I imported the library.

I tried copy/pasting code I found on the internet though that didn't work too.

```
import 'package:nyxx/nyxx.dart';
void main() {
  final bot = Nyxx("MTE0NjI1ODM3Nzc5MDQ3MjI2Mw.GQNPzH.NZYOGSrp-0BNuYTgjYmp5AsXRV_HJWQCQrTmKA");

  final stopwatch = Stopwatch();
  stopwatch.start();
  int day = 0;
  if(stopwatch.elapsed >= Duration(seconds: 60)){
    day++;
    print(day);
    stopwatch.reset();
  }
}
```

//yaml
name: test
description: A simple command-line application.
# version: 1.0.0
# homepage: https://www.example.com

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  nyxx: ^5.1.1

dev_dependencies:
  pedantic: ^1.11.0
```

Comment: Please add the full exact error message, some code that trigger the error and the `dependencies` section of your `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: Did you run `dart pub get`?